# Unable to change button's appearance properties

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a button that, when clicked, sets off a macro. I would like to change the Text and the BackColor properties when this happens, however it seems it does not have access to these properties. I get the below error with both lines.

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("excelToPPT").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("excelToPPT").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Working..."
```

[image]

Comment: Is the "button" an ActiveX control or a native PowerPoint object such as a rectangle shape?

Comment: It is an ActiveX control

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX buttons have pretty much the same properties as buttons on a userform. To access the properties, you drill down to the .OLEFormat.Object of the shape in question.  Like so, assuming your button is shape #3 on slide 1:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3)
    With .OLEFormat.Object
        .BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ' This sets the text color:
        .ForeColor = RGB(0, 255, 255)
    End With
End With
```